# An interactive learning widget for R using Quarto

Tags: r, widget, knitr, interactive, quarto

The following `Test.Rmd` will produce an interactive learning widget for [r](/questions/tagged/r) using [knitr](/questions/tagged/knitr) ([see the link](https://github.com/datacamp/tutorial)).

````
---
title: "Example Document"
author: "Your name here"
output:
  html_document:
    self_contained: false
---

```{r, include = FALSE}
tutorial::go_interactive()
```

By default, `tutorial` will convert all R chunks.

```{r}
a <- 2
b <- 3

a + b
```
````

**Edited**

Wondering how to an get an interactive learning widget for [r](/questions/tagged/r) using [quarto](/questions/tagged/quarto). Need help for YAML of .qmd, my attempt is

````
    ---
title: "Test"
author: "MYaseen208"
format: 
  html:
    self_contained: false
---



```{r}
#| echo: false
#| include: false
tutorial::go_interactive()
```

```{r}
#| echo: false
1 + 1
```


You can add options to executable code like this 

```{r}
#| echo: false
2 * 2
```

The `echo: false` option disables the printing of code (only output is displayed).
````

However, it throws the following error:

```
ERROR: Validation of YAML front matter failed.
ERROR: (line 5, columns 3--7) Field "html" has empty value but it must instead be an object
4: format: 
5:   html:
        ~
6: ---

ERROR: Render failed due to invalid YAML.
```

Another attempt which render but don't produce the required output:

```
---
title: "Test1"
author: "MYaseen208"
format: 
  html:
    output-file: "Test1.html"
    self-contained: false
---
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error, you should use `self-contained` instead of `self_contained` in [quarto](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/formats/html.html) like this:

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "MYaseen208"
format: 
  html:
    self-contained: false
---

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| include: false
tutorial::go_interactive()
```

```{r}
#| echo: false
1 + 1
```

You can add options to executable code like this 

```{r}
#| echo: false
2 * 2
```

The `echo: false` option disables the printing of code (only output is displayed).
````

Output:

[image]

---

I don't think the package is currently supported on Quarto, since the latest release of the [package](https://github.com/datacamp/tutorial) was in 2016. You might contact them about this.